# Interpreting "Infinite regular polygon with infinite sides" as topology

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Consider $S$ = a circle, $A[n]$ = regular polygon with $n$ sides, inscribed or circumscribed to $S$. (I think my interpretations work for both situations.) I want to state something like $\lim_{n\to\infty}A[n]=S$ appropriately.

(1) Let $X$ be the whole plane and $Z_S,Z_{A[n]}$ be corresponding closed sets of $X$ as usual topology.

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133030/defining-a-topology-in-the-power-set) I found that I can identify a closed set $Z \subset X$ as a continuous map $f:X\to 2$, where $2=\{0,1\}$, $\{0\}$ is closed and $\{1\}$ is not closed, by relating as $Z=f^{-1} (0)$.
Then there is a natural topology called "compact-open topology" in the set of continuous map $Cont(X,2)$.

Using this identification and compact-open topology, I recognized that the statement $\lim_{n\to\infty}Z_{A[n]}=Z_S$ can be interpreted as "For any compact set $K$ avoiding $Z_S$, there exists $N$ such that $K$ avoids $Z_{A[n]}$ for $n\geq N$".

It seemed to hold, but I noticed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}Z_{A[n]}=Z$ is also true for arbitrary large $Z \supset Z_S$. $\lim_{n\to\infty}Z_{A[n]}$ is not determined uniquely and I must choice smallest closed. I think this is not very nice.

(2) So instead, I considered defining $Shape=\{(U_i,Z,U_e)|U_i$ and $U_e$ are open, $Z$ is closed, they form partition of $X\}$ and interpreting $S,A[n]$ as the element of $Shape$ by corresponding interior/boundary/exterior of the shape to $U_i/Z/U_e$, respectively.

$Shape$ is equivalent to the set of continuous map $f:X\to 3$, where $3=\{0,1,2\}$, $\{1\}$ is closed and $\{0\},\{2\}$ is not closed, by relating as $U_i=f^{-1}(0), Z=f^{-1}(1), U_e=f^{-1}(2)$.

Using this identification and compact-open topology, $\lim_{n\to\infty}A[n]=S$ can be interpreted as "For any pair of compact sets $K \subset int(S)$ and $K' \subset ext(S)$, there exists $N$ such that $K \subset int(A[n])$ and $K' \subset ext(A[n])$ for $n\geq N$.

It holds, but other shape $(U_i,Z,U_e)$ also satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}A[n]=(U_i,Z,U_e)$ when $Z \supset \partial S$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}A[n]$ is not defined uniquely again.

**Questions**. Are my interpretations correct? Is such non-uniqueness inevitable? Is there another natural way?

Comment: Regarding another natural way, you can parameterize the regular polygon and circle with paths $\gamma_n, \gamma : [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}^2$ respectively and then state the convergence as $\lim_{n\to\infty} \gamma_n = \gamma$ uniformly as functions $[0,1] \to \Bbb{R}^2$ with standard topologies.